# Set request type & content type in CURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am using KODAK api to integrate photo print functionality in my website. All is working fine but it gives error message at the time of creating order as you can see on below URL

https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/?retailer=Target&app=PNMEMORYDEMO&country=US&app_version=1.0

If you are not able to see the error message, you can see message which I have got as error

## ------------------------------

HTTP Status 401

- type : Status report
- message:Method Not Allowed
- description : The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2

## ------------------------------

For that reason, I have also talked with kodak api technical support but they said that make sure to set the correct "Request method" as POST and "Content-Type" as application/x-www-form-urlencoded when making this call.

I have used cURL for making this call but doesn't know how to set request type & content type in CURL request.

I am using below code. Please suggest & correct me for the same.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/PNPlasqTouch_T1366049430039_OKS13105x64222081_CTARGET/status/current");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST ` shouldn't be `0`.

Comment: Other than that, you can add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to see what is being sent over the wire; when you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, the content type and method should be what's expected. What's `$data` btw?

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option to set `"Content-Type"` header. `POST` method is already specified in your script by `CURLOPT_POST` option

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

And final code will be;

```
$ch = curl_init("https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/PNPlasqTouch_T1366049430039_OKS13105x64222081_CTARGET/status/current");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "your_username:your_password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```

**Update:** You can see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more detail about setting http headers. Also you are using secured service, you may set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` as 1

Comment: result should be like this

{
        "result": {
        "orderId": "PNMEMORYDEMO_T1397680340273_OMHYDDAK9_CTARGET",
        "vendorOrderId": "MHYDDAK9",
        "uri": "https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/PNMEMORYDEMO_T1397680340273_OMHYDDAK9_CTARGET"
        },
        "status": {
        "code": "OK"
        }
        }

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="kdfs-realm"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1073
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 10:12:46 GMT

Comment: You need to set username and password on your curl request. See my updated answer

Comment: I have added username & password. Please see my below code

$ch = curl_init('ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/…); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);cu‌​rl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1)‌​;curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"USERNAME:P‌​ASSWORD");curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPH‌​EADER, array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));$result=curl_exec($ch)

Comment: And what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

By `HTTP Status 401` it means you are unauthorized. I have clicked your link and it asked for user/password. So set the authentication as follows:

```
// use your user/password at here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

Comment: I have insert the above code with correct login credentials but it's not working

Comment: result should be like this
 
       {
        "result": {
        "orderId": "PNMEMORYDEMO_T1397680340273_OMHYDDAK9_CTARGET",
        "vendorOrderId": "MHYDDAK9",
        "uri": "https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/PNMEMORYDEMO_T1397680340273_OMHYDDAK9_CTARGET"
        },
        "status": {
        "code": "OK"
        }
        }

Comment: What is your latest error now? Also run the code with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);` and show us the log print.

Comment: $ch = curl_init('https://ws.test.kdfse.com/vasp2/rest/order/?retailer=Target&app=PNMEMORYDEMO&country=US&app_version=1.0');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"USERNAME:PASSWORD");curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));$result=curl_exec($ch)

Comment: & got the below error
------------------------------
HTTP Status 401
type : Status report
message:Method Not Allowed
description : The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
-----------------------------